# Nautilus could not create

Tags: dns, user-accounts, bind

I have installed BIND 9.0 after successfully installation it created one user called named Uid =25 Gid =25

I tried to login with this user but I'm getting below error messages

Nautilus could not create the following required folders: /var/named/Desktop, /var/named/.nautilus.

could not update ICEauthority file /var/named/.ICEauthority

there is a problem with the configure server

(/usr/libexec/gconf-sanity-check2 exited with status 256)

what could be the problem let me know plz..

Comment: well, usually you would not log into a daemon account like `named`. why would you want to do so? these accounts are not usually configured for interactive login, and by changing the password, you may break the daemon. I will say what you describe sounds odd, my Bind9 install uses a user called `bind`. Either way, try `cat /etc/passwd | grep named`. if the home and shell parameters there are not like those for a normal user (for instance pointing to a dir in var or null or false), then you should not attempt login.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful information. i understand the problem now.